# Rails 3 remote form succeeding without calling controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, forms

I have a page with multiple forms created like this

```
<% arr.each do |obj| %>
    <%= form_tag('/addjobs', :class => "class", :method => "post", :remote => true) do %>
        # Field Tags
        <%= submit_tag("add!") %>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

And an action in my "main" controller called addjobs that looks like this

```
def addjobs
   puts "adding jobs"
end
```

My routes are all matched up.

```
match '/addjobs' => 'main#addjobs'
```

I also have jquery bindings to each form that make the form disappear upon ajax success. When I hit the submit button on any of them, the form disappears (ajax succeeded), the parameters its sending appear in my logs, but it doesn't appear that addjobs ever gets called ("adding jobs" is absent from my server logs). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'main', :action => :addjobs), :remote => true do %>
    #field tags
<% end %>
```

The :remote => true option makes Rails submit the request dynamically with AJAX, calling the :valider method in the 'controller_name' controller.

Answer (score -1):

`puts` prints in the console, not in the server logs

Use `logger.info` to print in the server logs (depending on the log level on your environment)

Comment: In Rails, when I start a local server, anything outputted with puts normally appears on the tailed server logs.

Comment: I'm using RubyMine IDE. When I use my local server in development, the `puts` messages only appear in the 'Console' tab. They're never in development.log file.

Comment: yeah sorry the Console tab is where I want it